# Whys is this site so hard to use..?

Tags: discussion

I've only used this site a few times for posting questions, but I find it so hard to use I don't really want to.  Endless logging in to sections. "Add a tag" but you can't without sufficient privileges.  I typed in my password 3 times before submitting this post.  The fact that the site allowed me to do so indicates that it's not me, but the site's architecture.  It's also actually quite hard to find the forum that you want to read.

I'm not a beginner at IT.

Could something be done to simplfy this?  You only log in once on other forum sites (including those where real currency financial transactions take place). Why is this one different?  Elitism?  Hmmm.  Take a leaf from Google's book...

Comment: FWIW, the add-a-tag restriction is very practical. Each site has its own tagging conventions and approach, and while _you_ may be able to be sensible and make something that fits in, many new users — including drive-by askers who never come back — aren't. If the existing tags don't match your question, or you think a new one needs to be created, just comment, and I'm sure someone will take care of it. Or, stick around — it's not hard at all to get the basic site rep needed to do things like that (in fact, you already have reached the threshold).

Answer (score 3):

We hear you. Lots of things are complicated in Stack Exchange communities, but a lot of it is intentional. [Here's the list of privileges you can earn](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) by asking and answering questions and building your reputation here. We structure our sites this way on purpose to ensure that our communities can maintain high-quality sources of information in the very long term without devolving into Yahoo! Answers.

You are right that login is complicated and kinda broken in some places, and it's being worked on. (Our dev team are not beginners at IT either.) But it's by design that you have to log in to separate communities separately. They are, well, separate. You earn your reputation there separately from any other community in the network, because each one has distinct customs and guidelines that do not carry over between them. However once you hit 200 rep on any site you get the benefit of the doubt on any site in the network and are automatically bumped up by 100 points. This grants you most of the common privileges you'd need most frequently on a site.

Comment: Thanks for the info on fixing the repetative login mechanism.  I'll reserve comment regarding seperation of the sites until it's fixed.

Comment: "Lots of things are complicated in Stack Exchange" is certainly true, especially in trying to reply to an answer abby.  Do you see the paradox that's been created?  A person can't add a tag without reputation, but can't get reputation without asking questions... If I try to announce a cure for cancer here, I have to ask several daft questions like "What's the best way to destroy the Universe?" beforehand.  There's a lot of good stuff on this site, but its' complexity and bureaucracy precludes a wider participation.  Example in point - I've run out of allowable comment spac